# sympy symbol printing with unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, sympy

I don't understand why these two symbols are printed differently:

```
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.printing import pprint
xa = symbols('x_a')
yb = symbols('y_b')
pprint(yb, use_unicode=True)
pprint(xa, use_unicode=True)
```

The output is:

```
y_b
xₐ
```

Why does `xa` get a real subscript and `yb` doesn't? Using the display function in sympy console and jupyter notebook displays `yb` as expected, of course, but I'm ultimately trying to log my sympy script in unicode (UTF-32) instead of UTF-8.

Python 3.8.8
IPython 7.22.0
Sympy 1.8
Pop!OS on System76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a subscript b in unicode:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Latin_and_Greek_tables

SymPy's unicode support is best effort but can only work with what unicode provides.